# Provider works in child but not in SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter, search, flutter-provider

This is the error:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<ListTile>> above this Widget
```

I have an app that displays items from a `FutureProvider`. I use the provider twice, one at the end to generate a `ListView` in the same page using `ListaProductos()`, and one at the `AppBar` to generate the same `ListView` on a `SearchDelegate`.

**This is the main page**:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (user != null) {
      return FutureProvider<List<ListTile>>.value(
        value:
            ServicioBaseDatos(usuarioUID: user.uid).listaProductos,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              "Stock",
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  var listaProductos = Provider.of<List<ListTile>>(context);
                  showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    delegate: SearchProducto(listaProductos),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => new CrearProductoPage())),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
          drawer: MenuComponent(user.email == null ? '' : user.email),
          body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Color(0xFFAE885E), Color(0xFF557A95)])),
              child: ListaProductos()),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text('Esperando identificador de usuario de la base de datos');
    }
  }
```

**This is the `ListaProductos()` widget** (works fine):

```
class ListaProductos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListaProductosState createState() => _ListaProductosState();
}

class _ListaProductosState extends State<ListaProductos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productos = Provider.of<List<ListTile>>(context);
    if (productos != null){
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: productos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  productos[index];
        },
      );
    }
    else {return Text('Esperando respuesta de base de datos');}
  }
}
```

**This is the `SearchDelegate` implementation** (The error appears when I click at the search icon that opens this page):

```
class SearchProducto extends SearchDelegate<ListTile> {

  final List<ListTile> listaProductos;

  SearchProducto(this.listaProductos);

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (listaProductos != null){
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listaProductos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  listaProductos[index];
        },
      );
    }
    else {return Text('Esperando respuesta de BD');}
  }
}
```

I'm halfway a [Boring show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI) but they don't use Provider. Ideas? Thanks for your help!

Edit: **This is the `value:` of the `FutureProvider`**:

```
Future<List<ListTile>> get listaProductos async {
    List<ListTile> listaProd = [];
    final documentos = await colecUsuario
        .document(usuarioUID)
        .collection('ListaItems')
        .getDocuments();
    if (documentos != null) {
      for (var doc in documentos.documents) {
        for (var k in doc.data.keys) {
          listaProd.add(
            ListTile(
             title: Text(k),
             trailing: Text(doc.data[k].toString()),
            )
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return listaProd;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

intentaste obtener la información dentro del Search en vez de pasarlo ?

```
class SearchProducto extends SearchDelegate<ListTile> {


  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final listaProductos = Provider.of<List<ListTile>>(context);
    if (listaProductos != null){
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listaProductos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  listaProductos[index];
        },
      );
    }
    else {return Text('Esperando respuesta de BD');}
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, si probé, y el error es el mismo